# PHP: Best way for implementing saving and loading ONE sentence

Tags: php

I'd like to implement a Systems Running or Systems Down indicator on the homepage of my website. An admin website will be changing the indicator. I see that using a database to do such a simple thing is inefficient. I currently am using fopen and fwrite to a file containing this sentence (in JSON), but I am worried that if multiple users accessed simultaneously then the file won't be ready to be read and would cause latency in the page loading.

What is the best way to implement such a thing?

Comment: A database is fine for this. You could cache the database record in Memcache if you want, but you'd need to be serving a lot of users before there is much value in that caching. Databases are fast.

Comment: Usually for this kind of things, they use a pid-file approach. All you need is to have this "true-false" trigger. When you start any service the file is created. When you stop it, it's deleted. So no need to read it at all, just check if file exists or not. If you need custom messages, you can place it in the file (may be even .php file with a variable and just include it)

Comment: Couldn't you just use `fsockopen()` to test if a port of a specific IP is listening or not and then just show a message depending on the true/false ?

Comment: @halfer I am very hesitant to create a whole table just for this sentence (it surely does not fit else where in my database).

Comment: @Axalix The sentence would be dynamic, but I see how this approach is much better.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy The sentence would be dynamic

Comment: Yes, for flags, a new table would be required (e.g. `system_state`). If you only have this variable, then you would only ever have one row. If you think a database is overkill here, then a file is also good. Worrying about the speed of either is probably a micro-optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are ideal for such things.

Comment: But sessions are clients' oriented. Can you explain further how would a session serve this purpose?

Comment: Sessions are not client oriented. Session COokies and session it self - not the same thing. You probably were thinking about session cookies, which are stored on client, but the session data, that's stored on server.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. How do I get all clients to read from the same session data which I can manage?

Comment: Of course, sessions are client oriented. That's the whole purpose of them.

Comment: Spooky, I think you've misunderstood the problem. The site indicator is intended to be per-site, not per-user.

Comment: It seems so... Looks like I did.. :D What about `file_get_contents()` that can be fast pretty much enough if You don't want to use database.. ?

Comment: You are using fopen/fwrite() or file_get_contents()  .. ? Now I am confused. :D

Comment: file_get_contents() is fopen, fread followed by fclose. file_put_contents is fopen, fwrite then fclose.

Comment: I know. But it is faster. It does the same thing in one shot, and file_get_contents()/file_put_contents() - is/are faster than fopen/fread/write/fclose. 

All in all, if You are already reading directly from the file, and file is not huge or has 10kb +/- latency should not be a problem. At least with Zend caching mechanism in never php versions. So, if You are not using php 5.3 but never version, You should not worry.

Comment: Yet, again, I don't understand why don't You rely on placing that particular file contents into a session once when it's being read .. and check for file changes with `filemtime` periodically? When file modification time is detected.. particular `$_SESSION['admin_state']` (for example) changes it's value.. and if ($this == $that)  .. You get the point.. :)